# filter Two property vs filtering one computed property ? datastore google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to build a chat application, this's my model:

```
class Message(ndb.Model):
  senderId = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  receiverId = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  sender_receiver = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.senderId.join('-').join(self.receiverId))
  message = ndb.StringProperty()
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

so if I want to get the messages to userId1 and userId2 with these values:  userId1 = 7878  , userId2=5264.
I will run the following query:

```
qry = Message.query(Message.sender_receiver.IN('7878-5264','5264-7878'));
```

but without computed property:

```
qry = Message.query(Message.sender.IN(7878,5264) AND Message.receiver.IN(7878,5264));
```

which is better ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats

Comment: @PaulCollingwood thank you I will use it :)

Comment: IN is expensive operation, better don't use it.

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi so what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

Use repeated property.

```
sender_receiver = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: [self.senderId, self.receiverId], repeated=True)

qry = Message.query()
qry = qry.filter(Message.sender_receiver == 7878)
qry = qry.filter(Message.sender_receiver == 5264)
# you will get all values where sender or receiver in 7878 or 5264 with a single query
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head (and going with what Dmitry said), In is an expensive and slow operation, since it creates multiple queries and then joins the results.

I would use the computed property, but I wouldn't even use the IN in it.

I'd do

```
 qry = Message.query(Message.sender_receiver = '7878-5264' OR Message.sender_receiver = '5264-7878');
```

the computed property will cost you a bit more time when doing saves, but it's a normal case of taking a bit more time to save so it can retrieve faster.

Comment: thank you for you response, but I think there is no difference between using IN and OR, right ? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in

Comment: @David totally right, forgot about that.... :/ yeah I think Dmitry's repeated property should do the trick then